# Passing double pointer to function

Tags: c, pointers

I was trying out some pointer and function interaction and found out this behavior. The first printf prints 100 but the second printf prints 0!

Can somebody help me understand why?

```
void ptr_change (int **p)
{       
    int y = 100;
    *p = &y;
}

int main ()
{

    int x = 7;
    int *p = &x;
    ptr_change(&p);
    printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);
    printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);
    return 0;

}
```

Compile:

```
gcc ptr2.c
```

Run and give output:

```
./a.out 

Ptr = 100
Ptr = 0
```

Comment: What is the idea behind doing this `*p = &y;`?

Answer (score 3):

`y` is an automatic local variable which will no longer exist after the function returns and you are assigning the address of an automatic local variable to the pointer.
In  the `main` function you are dereferencing a pointer which no longer points to a valid location. This invokes undefined behavior. You can't expect anything good once there is undefined behavior of your code.

Comment: @alk; Corrected my wordings.

Comment: But why doesnt the 1st printf give undefined output? Even that is trying to access the address of the local variable of function ptr_change(). Isnt it?

Comment: @vishals1991 yes, at that point the value of `y` still happens to be in memory at that address. But by the second call it has been overwritten.

Comment: @vishals1991 The 1st printf gave undefined output.  Undefined output can be anything.

Comment: @vishals1991: "*But why doesnt the 1st printf give undefined output?*" Undefined behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

You return the address of an automatic variable from a procedure. The variable is no longer valid after the function returns. What happens next is called Undefined Behavior, however, an explanation for Intel machines and e.g. VC2008 is:

```
ptr_change(&p);
```

This places in `p` the address of the local variable `y`. After return from function `ptr_change` the stack space used by the function is released.

```
printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);
```

This first printf re-uses the stack space used earlier by `ptr_change`. It pushes 2 parameters onto the stack. The first parameter overwrites the stack space used by `&p` in your function call. `y` is not yet overwritten. The `*p` parameter of printf gets this value and pushes it onto the stack. The call to printf now overwrites `int y`.

```
printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);
```

As `int y` has been overwritten in the previous cal to printf, this call to printf prints garbage.

Note that any other form of undefined behavior is possible!

Answer (score 1):

The value of `y` in

```
void ptr_change (int **p)
{       
    int y = 100;
    *p = &y;
}
```

exists only temporary on stack as an `automatic variable`.
Once the function returns that location is not longer valid.

Compare the following program which passes pointer to the variable `a` and initializes pointer `p`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void ptr_change2 (int **p, int *a)
{       
    *p = a;
}

int main ()
{
    int x = 7;
    int z = 8;

    int *p = &x;

    printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);

    ptr_change2(&p,&z);

    printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Ptr = 7
Ptr = 8
```

Answer (score -3):

```
*p = &y
```

is incorrect, you're assigning the address of y to the value of p.

try this instead:

```
p = &y
```

they will now have the same base address.

```
y = 100;
```

then print the pointer value of p

```
printf("%d", *p);
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8Etc2P16xw    <-- check this out to understand pointer and & operator more clearly. It helped me. Start at minute 57:00 !

Comment: `*p = &y ` is correct. He later dereference his variable to get its value.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where is the de-reference. I am a new C programmer too, still thought I'd try to answer the question. And help improve my knowledge as well.

Comment: He dereferences in `printf("\nPtr = %d", *p);`